# Create a Sharepoint:AspMenu for global navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I create a `navigation bar` in left side to get from `managed navigation`?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for my issue. In master page, we have navigation in top and quick launch in left side. You can copy code navigation bar from the top  to left side (in quick launch). This is my navigation bar code

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" role="navigation" runat="server">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
<template_controls>
                                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                                        ShowStartingNode="False"
                                        SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                                        id="topSiteMap"
                                        runat="server"
                                        StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
                                </template_controls>
                                                </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                                                    <SharePoint:AspMenu
                                                        ID="TopNavigationMenu"
                                                        Runat="server"
                                                        EnableViewState="false"
                                                        DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                                                        AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                                                        UseSimpleRendering="true"
                                                        UseSeparateCss="false"
                                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                        StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                                                        AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                                                        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                                                        SkipLinkText="" />
                                                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                            </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```